# TypeError when sending keys to text field with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I'm experiencing a very strange issue when trying to send text to a text field with Python.

This is my code:

```
keyword_text_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="558450155"]')
keyword_text_field.clear()
keyword_text_field.send_keys('Ford')
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mountNode"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[18]/div[2]/button')
search_button.click()
```

The url is the following:
https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/searchresults.xhtml?zip=84025&keywordPhrases=rebuilt%20title&startYear=2014&endYear=2018&sellerTypes=p&searchRadius=0&sortBy=derivedpriceDESC&numRecords=25&firstRecord=0

This is the error I get:

```
File "/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/AutoTraderScraper.py", line 34, in search_for_keyword
keyword_text_field.send_keys('Ford')
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
{'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

My environment techinical specs are the following:

- Python 2.7
- Chrome 68.0.3440.106
- Chromedriver 2.42
- Selenium 3.13

Any idea why this is happening? I have no problem sending keys to other text fields in the same site.

Comment: The error command within the error stack trace `keyword_text_field.send_keys(keyword_text_field)` **doesn't matches** your code `keyword_text_field.send_keys('Ford')`

Comment: Thanks. Already edited

Comment: stacktrace still doesn't match your code

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get not clear, but most likely you need to wait for element. Also you can get much better selectors like in code below:

```
keyword_text_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".accordion-panel-input input")))
keyword_text_field.clear()
keyword_text_field.send_keys('Ford')
driver.find_element_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your error using the same code; assume because of discrepancy in browser, driver or Selenium versions.

Also, keep in mind: different browsers **can** parse HTML/XML differently, so you might find discrepancies between browsers using xPath. CSS selectors are preferable and also less brittle insofar as easier to avoid deeply nested paths.

**environment**

- *os*: macOS 10.10.5
- *Python*: 3.6.1
- *Selenium*: 3.14.0
- *Gecko driver*: 0.21.0
- *Firefox*: 62.0

**code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/searchresults.xhtml?zip=84025&keywordPhrases=rebuilt%20title&startYear=2014&endYear=2018&sellerTypes=p&searchRadius=0&sortBy=derivedpriceDESC&numRecords=25&firstRecord=0")
keyword_text_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="558450155"]')
keyword_text_field.clear()
keyword_text_field.send_keys('Ford')
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mountNode"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[18]/div[2]/button')
search_button.click()
driver.close()
```